# Start applications on specific workspaces in xmonad

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I know how to associate specific applications with specific workspaces using manageHook and composeAll. What I'm looking for is a way to spawn applications on specific workspaces, i.e. a function with type signature `String -> workSpaceId -> X ()` whose example use would be something like:

```
spawnToWorkspace "emacs" "2:code"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, it was actually easier than I thought:

```
spawnToWorkspace :: String -> String -> X ()
spawnToWorkspace program workspace = do
                                      spawn program     
                                      windows $ W.greedyView workspace
```

Comment: This is the only solution that seems to work, it appears that `spawnOn` from XMonad-Contrib is broken with newer versions of XMonad.

Answer (score 9):

The more correct (and modern; I don't think SpawnOn was in the released XMonad back then, an awful lot of good stuff was only in darcs) way to do this is to

```
import XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn
```

and then use the action

```
spawnOn "2:code" "emacs"
```

See http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-SpawnOn.html for details.

Comment: Does this still work? I'm on xmonad 0.10 and using spawnOn still seems to just spawn the application on the current workspace...

Answer (score 0):

For [geekosaur's answer](https://superuser.com/a/478500/911683) to work you also need to tell XMonad to manage the Spawns using the `manageHook` setting:

```
xmonad $ def
{
  ...
  , ...
  , manageHook = manageSpawn <+> manageHook def
  , ...
}
```

After you include this setting `spawnOn` should work as expected.

Comment: Provided the program being spawned is a well-behaved X client that sets the `_NET_WM_PID` property (SpawnOn relies on this)