# How to spawn a program on a specific workspace at startup using XMonad?

Tags: xorg, xmonad, haskell

[Like](https://superuser.com/questions/478498/start-applications-on-specific-workspaces-in-xmonad), [many](https://superuser.com/questions/1417438/xmonad-spawn-mutliple-terminals-on-startup-on-different-workspaces), [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976044/xmonad-spawn-programs-on-startup-in-specified-workspace), I am trying to spawn a program on a specific Xmonad workspace at startup.

Here is my `xmonad.hs` that should start Firefox on workspace 4:

```haskell
import XMonad
import XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn

myStartupHook :: X()
myStartupHook = spawnOn "4" "/usr/bin/firefox"

main :: IO()
main = xmonad $ defaultConfig {
  modMask = mod4Mask,
  startupHook = myStartupHook,
  }
```

However, upon startup, Firefox is launched on workspace 1 instead of 4. According to [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/xmonad/comments/bcxm2y/spawnon_question_how_to_make_it_work/), all I need to do is add `manageSpawn` somewhere in this code. Here is what I tried:

```haskell
import XMonad
import XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn

myStartupHook :: X()
myStartupHook = spawnOn "4" "/usr/bin/firefox"

main :: IO()
main = xmonad $ defaultConfig {
  modMask = mod4Mask,
  startupHook = manageSpawn <+> myStartupHook,
  }
```

But I got the following error: `Couldn't match type Query (base-4.13.0.0:Data.Semigroup.Internal.Endo WindowSet) with X () Expected type: X () Actual type: ManageHook`. The [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Actions-SpawnOn.html) for spawnOn is not really helpful either.

What do I need to add the above `xmonad.hs` to start Firefox on workspace 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `manageSpawn` to be the *manageHook* rather than the *startupHook*. Here is a working `xmonad.hs` that spawns Firefox on workspace 4:

```haskell
import XMonad
import XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn

myStartupHook :: X()
myStartupHook = spawnOn "4" "/usr/bin/firefox"

main :: IO()
main = xmonad $ defaultConfig {
  modMask = mod4Mask,
  startupHook = myStartupHook,
  manageHook = manageSpawn
  }
```